# Angular ->Check the file been uploaded is open in some application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a field input type as File.I wanted to know if it is possible in a browser to check if the file which i have selected is opened in some other application or is currently been Edited.
I wanted to show the user as soon as they choose a file that "Please close the selected File,It is opened in some application or It is in Edit mode."

Comment: I think that is not possible or at least not very easy to achieve. But why would you like to check that? i think that it shouldn't matter for a simple file-upload.

Comment: I think you can use the file API and exceptions: https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#ErrorAndException , but I have never tried to achieve such a goal.